# Problem with the Foucault Pendulum motion derivation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, inertial-frames

A bad drawing just so you can see what I mean:
[image]

On every derivation I see, at some point it is stated that:
$$ \frac{T_x}{T}=\frac{-x}{L}$$ It is always explained by saying "by the geometry of the problem" or "by triangle similarity" but I fail to see how that follows so easily. This relation implies that as the x component of the mass gets larger, more tension is in that axis. That of course makes sense, but how is it possible to explicitly see this geometrically?

Answer (score 0):

It actually is straightforward geometry if you draw the figure properly. Look at $\theta$, the angle made by the pendulum with the $zy$ plane. It’s cosine is the required ratio.

[image]

Comment: And where is the minus x come from ? Because Tx

Comment: $\hat{x}$ and $\vec T_x$ point along opposite directions.